# Detecting memory leaks in Visual C++ (Windows)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, singleton, crtdbg.h

I'm working on a large C++ project under Visual Studio 2010 and think that there are some memory leaks inside. I tried the approach with including crtdbg.h but it does not help much as I don't see where the leaks occured. Defining new has 2 pitfalls: First it needs to be done in every cpp file which is not really an option, and 2nd it breaks with e.g. Boost. Using new(nothrow) or anything that uses boosts "has_new_operator.h" breaks this. [EDIT: It fails to compile as the redefined "new" has no overloads for something like "nothrow" or the "boost magic"] (Unless one defines "new" after all boost headers including headers referencing boost)

Last but not least: I have singletons. They are implemented using subclasses of the singleton template and a static function variable. One of them is a config container where one registers settings (pairs of strings and ints that are than stored in maps) Since the mem leak dump is called before deallocation of the singleton instance I get a massive amount of leaks for all those strings and the singleton itself.

Any way to have only the real leaks shown or make it dump after static object deallocation?

Which free tools can handle this case?

Comment: There are tools that are not free but provide fully functional trial. So you don't have to spend your money to check for the leaks.

Comment: Not quite sure if it exactly what you need but valgrind http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html provides tools to detct memory leakage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the Visual Leak Detector with quite positive results. It is small and neat, and can be built into your project (assuming you have a running Debug configuration) in a matter of seconds:

https://vld.codeplex.com/

If set-up correctly (which can be done using the installer) then you only have to

```
#include <vld.h>
```

in *one* of your .cpp files for each module - that's it, the header will do the linking for you. You don't have to put it everywhere. Internally the tool uses the CrtDbg, so you have to have a debug build running in order for it to work.

It gives you debugger or text output after each run (if configured using a config file), even when not run through a debugger. It is not the most powerfull tool, but these usually cost some coin ;)

**EDIT**: There is a possibility to enable the VLD also in non-debug configurations by defining `VLD_FORCE_ENABLE` before including the header. But the results may be tempered with then.

**EDIT**: I have tried a fresh installation of VLD. Note that for VS2013 compilers the v2.4rc2 version must be used (or anything greater v2.3). Version v2.3 only works up until VS2010 compilers.

After installation I created a new project and set-up my include- and library-directories to include the respective VLD folders. After that I used the following code to test memleak reports of singletons (note that this code doesn't make sense, it just proves a point):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

// Uncomment this, if you want VLD to work in non-debug configurations
//#define VLD_FORCE_ENABLE

#include <vld.h>

class FooSingleton {
    private:
        std::map<std::string, std::string*>
            _map;

        FooSingleton() {
        }

    public:
        static FooSingleton* getInstance(void) {
            /* THIS WOULD CAUSE LEAKS TO BE DETECTED
               SINCE THE DESTRUCTOR WILL NEVER BE CALLEd
               AND THE MAP IS NOT CLEARED.
            */
            // FooSingleton* instance = new FooSingleton;
            // return instance;

            static FooSingleton instance;
            return &instance;
        }

        void addString(const std::string& val) {
            _map.insert(std::make_pair(val, new std::string(val)));
        }

        ~FooSingleton(void) {
            auto it = _map.begin();
            auto ite = _map.end();

            for(; it != ite; ++it) {
                delete it->second;
            }
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FooSingleton* fs = FooSingleton::getInstance();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << i << "nth string.";
        fs->addString(ss.str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With this code, the VLD does not report any leaks because the static auto-variable in `getInstance()` will be destructed upon exit and the elements in the map will be deleted. This must be done nevertheless, even if it's a singleton, otherwise the leaks will be reported. But in this case:

```
Visual Leak Detector Version 2.3 installed.
Aggregating duplicate leaks.
Outputting the report to the debugger and to D:\dev\projects\tmp\memleak\memleak\memory_leak_report.txt
No memory leaks detected. Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
```

If the code in the `getInstance()` is changed to the commented version, then the singleton is never cleared up and the following leaks (amongst others) is reported:

```
---------- Block 11 at 0x008E5928: 52 bytes ----------
Leak Hash: 0x973608A9 Count: 100
  Call Stack:
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory (36): memleak.exe!std::_Allocate<std::_Tree_nod<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > *,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::alloca + 0x15 bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory (187): memleak.exe!std::allocator<std::_Tree_nod<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > *,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::alloca + 0xB bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree (560): memleak.exe!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > *,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,s + 0xD bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree (588): memleak.exe!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > *,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,s + 0x8 bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree (756): memleak.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > *,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std:: + 0x17 bytes
    d:\dev\projects\tmp\memleak\memleak\main.cpp (33): memleak.exe!FooSingleton::addString + 0xA9 bytes
    d:\dev\projects\tmp\memleak\memleak\main.cpp (51): memleak.exe!main + 0x37 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (555): memleak.exe!__tmainCRTStartup + 0x19 bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (371): memleak.exe!mainCRTStartup
    0x76BF919F (File and line number not available): KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xE bytes
    0x7739A22B (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x84 bytes
    0x7739A201 (File and line number not available): ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x5A bytes
  Data:
    C0 53 8E 00    30 67 8E 00    C0 53 8E 00    98 58 8E 00     .S..0g.. .S...X..
    30 6E 74 68    20 73 74 72    69 6E 67 2E    00 CD CD CD     0nth.str ing.....
    0C 00 00 00    0F 00 00 00    CD CD CD CD    48 56 8E 00     ........ ....HV..
    01 00 CD CD
```

You can clearly see the `Count: 100` for this block of code, which is correct.

I also edited my `vld.ini` file in the installation directory to have the following set to be enabled:

```
AggregateDuplicates = yes
ReportTo = both
```

These make sure that a) all duplicate leaks are squashed together to one report with a leak-count (as above, otherwise there would be 100 entries) and the other so that a report-file is dumped in the directory of the application.

So for singletons it works fine as long as you use the static auto-variable approach you are using and do your cleanup in the destructor.

**EDIT**: Also, the instrumentation can be disabled at specific code pieces. If the above code would be modified like this:

```
void addString(const std::string& val) {
    VLDDisable();
    _map.insert(std::make_pair(val, new std::string(val)));
    VLDEnable();
}
```

The leaks will *never* be profiled and not tracked.

Comment: If it uses crtDbg, does it handle singletons? Is there anything I can do so that the singletons aren't shown as leaks anymore? (Damn I'd love something like valgrind for windows...)

Comment: @Flamefire I think the singletons will show up because they are never deleted if dynamically created in the `getInstance()`. I can't say for sure to be honest, you'd have to check that yourself, sorry. But assuming that you are expecting these as leaks, they should not trouble you and can be filtered out quite easily - also because they are only reported once, and real nasty leaks show up hundred of times ;)

Comment: @Flamefire Addition: If you just return the address of a static auto-variable in your `getInstance()` (or however you access your singleton) then it should be fine, because they will be cleaned up on exit. Just the `new` would never have a counterpart `delete` that could be checked for by the VLD. And there is also an API with which you can enable/disable the VLD at runtime (`VLDDisable()` and `VLDEnable()`). These might work if you put them around your singleton allocation.

Comment: The main problem is not really the singleton itself, but the maps in it. I get like 100 reports for leaked strings and related data. Hard to filter those out. The function is like that: T& getInstance(){static T instance; return instance;}
I just found I can use memory store points in crtDbg (like get mem leaks in a specified timeframe) is this also possible with some other tools like VLD? I assume this would solve the singleton issue unless new strings are inserted in between.

Comment: @Flamefire Hm, I am not sure about other free tools that would accomplish that (not that there aren't any). But the way VLD is reporting leaks is that it will print the callstack _once_ with a cound on how often that piece of code leaked. So even if there are 100+ leaks, there would only be one entry in your logs (which again, should be easily be filtered out). You can use the above mentioned API calls to enable/disable VLD for a time-frame (kinda). I assume the best thing is to just try it out. In the meantime there might be other answers coming in :)

Comment: @Flamefire Please read the edited version of my answer, I tested it :)

Comment: I tried that today and it works as expected. I though VLD would just use crtDbg under the hood and therefore has the same problems.
VLD is great for that purpose!

Answer (score 0):

You can get memory leaks source from `crtdebug`. it won't help you with the boost allocations, unless you compile boost (or any library) in the same way, but for the rest, it will show you allocation file and line.

This is how you use properly the `crtdebug.h`:

in the top of your `stdafx.h` (or any PCH file) add the following lines:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    //must define both _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC and _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC_NEW
    #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
    #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC_NEW

    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <crtdbg.h>
    //if you won't use this macro you'll get all new as called from crtdbg.h      
    #define DEBUG_NEW   new( _CLIENT_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
    #define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

Now in the beginning of your `main` or `winmain` or any entry point to your program add the following lines:

```
//register memory leak check at end of execution: 
//(if you use this you won't need to use _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks at the end of your main)
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
//set report mode:
_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );
```

Now here a small test I've made:

After a new console program from VS10 called "test":
My stdafx.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef _DEBUG
  #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
  #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC_NEW
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <crtdbg.h>

  #define DEBUG_NEW   new( _CLIENT_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)
  #define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

and my test.cpp is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
void CheckMemoryLeak()
{
    char *ptr=new char[100];
    int n=900;
    sprintf(ptr,"%d",n);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );

    CheckMemoryLeak();

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
'tests.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\shr\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\tests\Debug\tests.exe', Symbols loaded.
'tests.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'tests.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'tests.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'tests.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
c:\users\shr\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\tests\tests\tests.cpp(9) : {97} client block at 0x01003288, subtype 0, 100 bytes long.
 Data: <900             > 39 30 30 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
The program '[1600] tests.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question: This does not help. I'd need to do that in every cpp file of the project or include a header in every cpp file (stdafx.h is not used consistently) Also it fails in many cases (boost, nothrow,...) due to the macro.

Comment: 1. If you'll compile boost or any other lib with this, then it will detect memory leaks in the libraries too. 2. visual studio default is to use pre-compiled-header, you might as well fix the `crtdbg.h` but anyway you'll need to include it on the top of any source file, which is the same work.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough: Using boost with this breaks compilation!
And as mentioned: I cannot change the whole big project just to check for mem leaks.